# Is it possible to install QtSvg for PyQt5 using PyCharm into a venv (not using os packages via apt-get, et cetera)?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt5, qtsvg

My Python3 project needs the QtSvg module (from PyQt5) on Python3. How can I (automatically) install the missing QtSvg using PyCharm into a venv, etc.?

I'm aware of the fact that there are OS distribution-specific packages on top of the base python3-pyqt5 which bring in QtSvg separately. However, I want to allow the users of my PyPI package (`linuxns-rel`) to simply install my package through `pip3`.

Is installing QtSvg for PyQt5 via PyCharms package management possible at all? I tried installing PyQt5 via PyCharms project package management to install it into a project-specific venv, but this always fails to bring in QtSvg.

Note: manually removing PyQt5 using the project-specific `venv/bin/pip3` and then installing PyQt5 again using `--no-cache-dir` with the `venv/bin/pip3` finally brings in a working PyQt5.

Were I am bitten by a broken PyQt5 package then? How do I correctly install a fully PyQt5 from within PyCharm into a venv?

Comment: Yes, PyQt5 has been installed via pip3. `import PyQt5` works, but `import PyQt5.QtSvg` fails.

Comment: PyQt is version 5.11.2

Comment: Yes, actually used `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSvg, QtCore` and this fails with `ImportError: cannot import name 'QtSvg'`.

Comment: Hm, doesn't work on Kubuntu 18.04LTS using PyCharm 2018.2 and installing into a venv. Strange, as I tried a lot of things before posting my question.

Comment: Yes, basic UIs work, only QtSvg fails.

Comment: Argh, removed PyQt5 using venv pip3 in terminal session; then installed PyQt5 via venv pip3 again using --no-cache-dir just in case ... and now it works. So this is some caching/PyCharm/pip3 installation hiccup.

Comment: the problem is pycharm then, it is not venv, if you want help share the configuration you have in pycharm

Comment: How is PyCharm not venv when I created a venv project-specific interpreter and I've now used the venv that I created in PyCharm? Where's the gotcha, as this would be really good to know?

Comment: I recommend you edit your question and point out that the problem is PyCharm also changing the tags